# Automatic Black screen with cursor on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: freeze, bug-reporting, ubuntu-budgie

I was browsing on Chrome and suddenly a black screen appears with a cursor. The only option left was to power off using switch. This happened to me very first time.Do anyone know the reason and how to fix this ? (Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.3 LTS).

Comment: Looks like a graphical failure. Has it occurred again since?

Comment: @ChanganAuto No, this happened only once.